# Regex value not matching with email IDs from CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am trying to have a basic check for Email IDs present in the CSV file. I don't know why is it not going thorough the "if" checks.

```
import csv
import re
input_file = open("test_list.csv", "r").readlines()
print(len(input_file))
csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file)
line_count = 0
try:
    for row in csv_reader:
        line_count += 1
        print('Checking ' + str(line_count) + ' of ' + str(len(input_file)))
        name = {row[0]}
        email = list({row[2]})
        print(str(email[0]))
        print('Checking contact name'+str(name))
        regex = '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$'
        match = re.match(regex,str(email[0]))
        if match == None :
            print("Bad Email")
        else:
            print("Good Email") 
        print('')
        print('')
except IndexError as error:
    print('Checked all the data')
```

My csv file is like this:

```
bhanu1, singh2, bha.nu@gmail.com
bhanu2, singh2, bhadoxit.com
bhanu3, singh2, bhan@esnotexit.com
```

My Output is:

```
3
Checking 1 of 3
 bha.nu@gmail.com
Checking contact nameset(['bhanu1'])
Bad Email

Checking 2 of 3
 bhadoxit.com
Checking contact nameset(['bhanu2'])
Bad Email

Checking 3 of 3
 bhan@esnotexit.com
Checking contact nameset(['bhanu3'])
Bad Email
```

Comment: your indents are wrong. You should indent the code of the for-loop otherwise the loop is empty

Comment: If the dash "-" can be part of email it should be escaped in square brackets. Like this: [a-z0-9\-]

Comment: @Gnudiff No, a dash can be last in a character class without escaping.

Comment: The problem is that you have a space before each email, you can see it in your ouput. so you should add a `strip()` to your matching:  `re.match(regex,str(email[0]).strip())` and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your email addresses begin with a space because you are not trimming adjacent spaces.

Also, your code has a large number of very odd and roundabout ways of manipulating your data.  Here is a refactoring with inline comments.

```
import csv
import re

input_file = open("test_list.csv", "r").readlines()
print(len(input_file))

csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file)
# Compile regex once, use multiple times inside loop
regex = re.compile(
    r'^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$')
try:
    for line_count, row in enumerate(csv_reader, 1):
        print('Checking {0} of {1}'.format(line_count, len(input_file)))
        # Don't make a set out of this
        name = row[0]
        # Don't make a list out of this; trim spaces
        email = row[2].strip()
        print(email)
        print('Checking contact name {}'.format(name))
        match = regex.match(email)
        if match is None:
            print("Bad Email")
        else:
            print("Good Email") 
        print('')
except IndexError as error:
    print('Checked all the data')
```

The `try`/`except` handling is still weird, and reading the file into memory and *then* reading it as CSV is rather clumsy.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for refining my code. What do you suggest for the handling? I am new to these things. Suggest the solution and I would love to incorporate it in my code.

Comment: If you don't need to know ahead of time how many lines there are, you can just open the file and start looping.  The `try`/`except` does not appear to do anything useful at the moment so maybe just take it out

Comment: If I am not using try catch it will give me an IndexError for being out of bound. What should I do about that?

Comment: My guess is that you have some lines in your csv, which are either empty or do not have 3 values. Then your access to `row[0]` or `row[2]` produces the error, you could check for the length of row in the beginning of your loop and if it is not 3, you might want to skip that line of the csv

Comment: I cannot reproduce the IndexError with the sample data you posted.  Trapping the error and making the program claim it processed all the data when the error specifically caused it not to process all the data seems misleading anyway.

Comment: @tripleee I got your point. I will remove the exception handling and loop it that many times only as the number of rows.

Comment: Yes @gaw I will have data as such where I wont be having the last names. How should I tackle that. What I mean to say is I may have a data as :
fname,fname@gmail.com or just the email
I would want to catch the mail ID anyways and check it.
Can you suggest any way for that?

Comment: That sounds really like a separate question, not a comment on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your ouput you can see a space in front of your email. If you remove this it should work fine. Just add `strip()` to your code for the matching.

```
match = re.match(regex,str(email[0]).strip())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that little space. It got me to pull of my hair.